# Can't read firebase Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project in which I want to read firebase Data without authenticating I have already changed my database rules to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

I have also tried

```
"rules": {
  ".read": "true",
  ".write": "auth != null"
}
```

[image: firebase structure image]

my code is:

```
 db = Database.database().reference()
    db.child("users").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)

    })

}
```

its not giving me any errors its just not pulling the data

Comment: go to your rules in the console and test them out there

Comment: Try `true` with  no quotes: `".read": true,` .. And as @PeterHaddad mentioned: You can use the simulator to test your rules in the Firebase console

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes: while `true` without quotes is more directly what is meant, `"true"` will work the same (since it's [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)).

Comment: The code you shared looks fine, so the problem is likely to be elsewhere. How do you run this code? How do you check that it's not pulling data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I run it on Xcode, and I know because it doesn't print anything in the console

Comment: Thanks for those. I assume you call this code from somewhere in your app. Maybe knowing more about that will help us find the problem. Essentially: if I take your code and data and stuff it into my xcode project, it will likely work (I don't see anything wrong with it at least). If you [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful) someone is more likely to see what's going on/wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you ensure that your setting is true. Check this code.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
print(ref)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
if !snapshot.exists() { return }
print(snapshot)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. as @Rosário Pereira Fernandes says, the error was on having quotes in the rules of my firebase database.

like this:

```
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": "auth != null"
}
```